# What technique in Photoshop can we use to produce animated drawing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

I came across a video that teaches kids how to draw. I recognize some kind of masking is involved, but I can't quite figure out how to do this in photoshop to create animated drawing. I know for sure the letters are pre-drawn in Photoshop (or some software), but I can't figure out the animation.

Here is the video I was referring to: https://youtu.be/ayzVNkIJsk8?t=31
 (warning, there's kid music).

Thoughts? If this is the wrong place to ask let me know, thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that kinda thing is done with After Effects

Comment: For what it's worth... I wouldn't be surprised if this was a screen recording where they erased each letter using like some form of Eraser tool and then reversed the video. It doesn't look incredibly professional, but I thought I'd mention it since it's a method that could be done using almost any application and should be doable even if you've never used the application before. Many screen recorders allow hiding the cursor...

Comment: Right after I commented, I had a flashback to the video and realized the text stroke cap curved outwards, so it probably wasn't done that way... I'm actually not sure how it was done.. because unmasking with a brush would be difficult when you can't see the letters... oh well...it doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it is a screen recording, the clue is the irregular window scrolling using the space bar at minute 0.34.

[image: Screen recording]

From an outlined text, use Color Range to get the outline selection

[image: outlined text]

- Hide the text layer and create a new empty layer.
- Make an Action with **Allow Tool Recording** checked from the
  Action's Menu
- Start recording painting with the brush inside the selection, following the text border

[image: Letter A]

Stop the action, delete this layer, make a new one, hide the selection and play the action:

[image: end]

Make a new layer to play the action while recording the screen or the document window

Comment: HOLY COW. Thank you so much for demonstrating this... what did you use? after effect? (edit: oh never mind it's photoshop).

Comment: I tried this and it looks awesome, except after I did color range, did the select, hid the text layer, created a new layer, my brush is filling "underneath" the selection. Please see https://imgur.com/a/7NbSCha. Am I missing a step? Thanks.

Comment: You must invert the selection to paint inside the letter

Comment: That works! You are amazing. Thank you, Daniel.